# Google Maps API - Onscreen Keyboard "Go!"

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google maps API to place a map onto a web page.

As the Computer with the map has not a keyboard, I simulate a javascript "onscreen" keyboard. My problem is that I don't know how to generate the "Enter" key.

My map has a searchbox (libraries=places), where the user input his choice.
On a normal computer I press enter to "search", how can I do that with my onscreen keyboard?

Thank you!

Comment: can you use jquery? @Perocat

Comment: Yes, the keyboard is jQuery!

Comment: So, you can use the trigger event to simulate the enter key press! $("input").blur(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 15; // Enter
    $("input").trigger(e);
});

Comment: doesn't work... I already tried that... Enter is not 13?

Comment: Unfortunately, same thing with "13"

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle code example to make it easier for us to help

Comment: Something happen when the 'e' is triggered?